# Rolling sum with unbalanced panel with non-even times in Stata

Tags: stata

I have an unbalanced daily panel where entries occur at uneven times. I would like to generate the rolling sum of some variable `x` over the past 365 days. I can think of two ways to do this, but the first is memory hungry and the second is processor hungry. Is there a third alternative that avoids these problems?

Here are my two solutions. Is there a third solution without memory or speed problems?

```
clear
set obs 200
set seed 2001

/* panel variables */
generate id = 1 + int(2*runiform())
generate time = mdy(1, 1, 2000) + int(10*365*runiform())
format time %td
duplicates drop
xtset id time

/* data */
generate x = runiform()

/* first approach is to fill the panel with `tsfill` */
/* then remove "seasonality" with `s.` */
tsfill
generate sx = sum(x)
generate ssx = s365.sx

/* second approach without `tsfill` */
/* but nested loop is fairly slow */
drop if missing(x)
generate double ssx_alt = 0
forvalues i = 1/`= _N' {
    local j = `i'
    local delta = time[`i'] - time[`j']
    while ((`j' > 0) & (`delta' < 365) & (id[`i'] == id[`j'])) {
        local x = cond(missing(x[`j']), 0, x[`j'])
        replace ssx_alt = ssx_alt + `x' in `i'
        local j = `j' - 1
        local delta = time[`i'] - time[`j']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum over the last # days is the difference between two cumulative sums, the cumulative sum to now and the cumulative sum to # days ago. The extension to panel data is easy, but not shown here. I don't think gaps disturb this principle once you have applied `tsfill`.

```
. set obs 20
obs was 0, now 20

. gen t = _n

. gen y = 100 + _n

. gen sumy = sum(y)

. tsset t
    time variable:  t, 1 to 20
            delta:  1 unit

. gen diff = sumy - L10.sumy
(10 missing values generated)

. l

     +------------------------+
    |  t     y   sumy   diff |
    |------------------------|
 1. |  1   101    101      . |
 2. |  2   102    203      . |
 3. |  3   103    306      . |
 4. |  4   104    410      . |
 5. |  5   105    515      . |
    |------------------------|
 6. |  6   106    621      . |
 7. |  7   107    728      . |
 8. |  8   108    836      . |
 9. |  9   109    945      . |
10. | 10   110   1055      . |
    |------------------------|
11. | 11   111   1166   1065 |
12. | 12   112   1278   1075 |
13. | 13   113   1391   1085 |
14. | 14   114   1505   1095 |
15. | 15   115   1620   1105 |
    |------------------------|
16. | 16   116   1736   1115 |
17. | 17   117   1853   1125 |
18. | 18   118   1971   1135 |
19. | 19   119   2090   1145 |
20. | 20   120   2210   1155 |
     +------------------------+
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! This is the same as my first approach, but I didn't realize that with the time series operators I *don't have* to fill in the panel first (that would only be necessary with the `[_n - 1]` subscripts). Thanks.